# kd-tree for clustered data

Tags: search, kdtree

I am looking for a kd-tree for clustered data.
I have a large data set and in some areas the data is highly dense.
So I need some "balanced" search. 
When I do a search for n-neighbors  with a point next to a dense area I want 
a result which is spatially "balanced". The search result must contain
also data points from the sparse area.
Is there any implementation which can do this job?

Thank you
Jan

Comment: How would you define this formally? It's not the k nearest neighbors anymore then... much of the idea of the k nearest neighbors is to adapt to density differences; and not get such outside points when in a dense area...

Answer (score 0):

A weighted voronoi diagram is spatialy balanced.